# Ruby on Rails - User roles with STI query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For my user roles I have switched to a Single Table Inheritance solution for my project from a previous roles solution with a simple boolean method. I am using Devise. STI appears to work in my project but I am wondering how I can get this to work in my views?

For example I used to say <% if current_user.teacher? %>....<% end %> and this worked for hiding things from different users and so on. Now I have a "type" column in my users table to support STI and I am wondering how would the above be implemented with this (it's teacher too)?

Teacher.rb

```
class Teacher < User

end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.teacher? %>
      <%= link_to "Create Homework Assignment", new_homework_path, class: "btn-custom" %>
      <a class="btn-custom" href= "/homeworks/homework_completed" role="button"><i class="fa fa-sm fa-check green-tick"></i>Completed Homework Table</a>
      <% end %>
```

Thanks. More info if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask whether your user is an instance of a Teacher:

```
<% if current_user.is_a? Teacher %>
```

Alternatively you can add a `teacher?` method to your `User` class which does the check for you and keep the same DSL:

```
def teacher?
  is_a? Teacher
end
```

Comment: Just to ask (i'd rather not have to correct all of these filters) what would the "teacher?" method look like? I currently have def teacher?
 teacher
end

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much!